# what is the logic behind its output ? Its giving the same output for both Break and continue

Tags: javascript, continue

First of all, I'm confused about output? How this output can possible?

I have tried many logic but didn't get a universal logic/

**with 'break; statement:**

```js
for (var i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {
  if (i == 5) {
    break;
  }
  i++;
  console.log(i);
}
```

**with 'continue' statement:**

```js
for (var i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
        continue;
    }
    i++;
    console.log(i);
}
```

**Output is same for both: 3 5  7  9**

Comment: it counts even numbers. you never get `5`.

Comment: Your `for` increments `i` **and** you increment it manually. So your loop step is 2, not 1 => you never reach `5`, only `4` and `6`.

Comment: The result is the same because `i` is never `5` at the time of checking.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the double increment, inside of the block and inside of the `for` statement, you get only even numbers for checking.

```js
//                                                     loop   1   2   3   4
//                                                     ---- --- --- --- ---      
for (var i = 2; i <= 8; i++) { // increment                   2   4   6   8
    console.log('top', i);     // always even                 2   4   6   8
    if (i == 5) {              // check with even value       2   4   6   8
        // continue;
        // break
    }
    i++;                       // increment                   3   5   7   9
    console.log('bot', i);     // always odd                  3   5   7   9
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! So how about this code mentioned below, I'm getting 5 7 9 as output but 5 sholdl not be there because of continue statement 

for (var i=4; i<=8; i++) {
  if (i==5) {
    continue;
  }
  i++;
  console.log(i);
}

Comment: no, the problem is **not** the start value, but `i++;`. the condition is never `true`, because `i` is never `5`. `i` has always an even value.

Answer (score 0):

As we all know,

- **Continue** - The continue statement terminates execution of the current iteration in a loop.
- **Break** - The break statement breaks (stops) the execution of a loop entirely.

In this code,

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {
  if (i == 5) {
    break; / continue;
  }
  i++;
  console.log(i);
}
```

Your `i` is incremented two times, one in `loop` and another in `loop body` i.e. manual increment.

In this case loop goes through below steps,

**Loop Iteration 1,**

1. i = 2
2. enters loop and checks,

   if (i == 5) {
   break; / continue;
   } //as `i=2` this is false and does not enter into if condition
3. i++ // `i` incremented to 3 now
4. console.log(i) //print 3
5. checks i<=8 // true
6. if step 5 true then i++ //now `i` increment to 4

**Loop iteration 2,**

7. enter loop and check,

   if (i == 5) {
   break; / continue;
   } //as `i=4` this is false and does not enter into if condition
8. i++ // `i` incremented to 5 now
9. console.log(i) //print 5
10. checks i<=8 // true
11. if step 10 true then i++ //now `i` increment to 6

**Loop iteration 3,**

12. enter loop and check,

    if (i == 5) {
    break; / continue;
    } //as `i=6` this is false and does not enter into if condition

and continues with next steps as above.

**So finally conclusion,**

Your both code snippet never enters if condition i.e.

```
if (i == 5) {
    break; / continue;
}
```

**Therefore your code never breaks / continue.**